# Function to calculate cumsum for multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, cumsum

I have a data frame as shown below:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:10, each = 101*10), 
             year = rep(rep(2001:2010, each = 101), times = 10),
             day = rep(rep(250:350, times = 10), times = 10),
             ref.rain = rep(c(400,500,450,430,470,576,644,230,850,690), each = 10*101),
             rain = runif(min = 0, max = 20, 10*101*10))
```

The dataframe has data for 10 locations. For each location, I have rainfall data from doy 250 till doy 350 for 2001 till 2010. The `ref.rain` is a reference rainfall for each location which is same for all the years for a location but different for each of the 10 locations.

For each location and each year, I want to determine the number of days (from doy 250) it takes for the cumulative rainfall to reach 1%, 2%, 3%....5% of the reference rainfall for that location. This is what I did

```
# define a function which does the job 

my.fun <- function(x,y){ifelse(sum(cumsum(x) >= y) == 0, NA, which.max(cumsum(x) >= y))} 

df1 <- data.table(df %>% group_by(loc.id,year) %>% 
            mutate(rain.01 = ref.rain*0.01, # calculate 1% of the ref.rain
                   rain.02 = ref.rain*0.02,
                   rain.03 = ref.rain*0.03,
                   rain.04 = ref.rain*0.04,
                   rain.05 = ref.rain*0.05) %>% 
            summarise(days2rain01 = my.fun(rain,rain.01), # apply the function that gives the no. of days to reach 1% 
                      days2rain02 = my.fun(rain,rain.02),
                      days2rain03 = my.fun(rain,rain.03),
                      days2rain04 = my.fun(rain,rain.04),
                      days2rain05 = my.fun(rain,rain.05)))
```

My issue is that I want the `my.fun` to be flexible enough so that I can compute no. of days for any % rainfall (1%, 2%,3%,........50%). At the moment, if I want to calculate more percentage, I have to add an additional `rain.XX = ref.rain*XX` argument and then add an additional `days2rainXX = my.fun(rain,rain.XX`) argument. How can the function be written so that it takes a vector of percentages and produces the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
# Create vector of percents
pct <- seq(0.01, 0.05, 0.01)
# Create reference rainfall columns 
df[paste0('rain', pct)] <- lapply(pct, `*`, df$ref.rain)
# summarise at new columns, with grouping
df %>% 
    group_by(loc.id, year) %>%  
    summarise_at(paste0('rain', pct), my.fun, x = as.name('rain'))
```

I'm not sure if this is any faster or clearer, but your function could also be

```
myfun <- function(x, y) which(cumsum(x) >= y)[1]
```